# how to calculate the number of touches on a button in android

Tags: java, android

hi i am a new developer. i am trying to design an app. In my app i want to calculate the no of touches in a particular button. Is this can be calculated by onTouch process if yes can anyone give me an example or idea.

Comment: I haven't found any particular API for this purpose, but I feel you can implement your own algorithm for this very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A click on a button is sent to the app via the `onClick` event. So if you have a Button:

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
myButton.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
```

You can set  up your onClickListener to do whatever you want when the button is clicked.

```
// Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
private OnClickListener myClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // increment the counter on click
        numberOfClicks++;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Try below code

1. First Create an Global variable

   **int numberOfClick = 0;**
2. Now for your button try following code

   ```
   clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
            numberOfClick++;
      }
   }
   ```

now you can get the number of clicks by this variable